# GLSL Deprecation

Tags: opengl, deprecated, glew

I've been upgrading my project in sections. I'm currently still using gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix in the meantime.

I'm using OpenGL 3.1 Compatablity 1.4 GLSL This works fine on my computer. When I try to move it to another computer it gives me the following error:

C7533: global variable gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix is deprecated after version 120

Why would one computer allow deprecated functionality and another not? Is there something I need to move to this other computer? This sounds like a warning, but the objects were either not drawn or not translated.

Comment: Deprecated usually doesn't mean "it ain't no longer working" - it is more of a note to consider moving away from it. It may be beyond deprecated in a more recent implementation.

Comment: This warning only appears on the second computer. It also does not work (objects are not drawn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLSL shader version and context version are two separate things, by the way. It is true that `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` is *deprecated* after GLSL 1.20 (introduced in GL 2.1) because GL 3.0 deprecated (and GL 3.1 without `GL_ARB_compatibility` removed) the entire fixed-function matrix stack. GLSL version 1.50 introduces profiles to GLSL, which are still independent from the context version, but work the same way -- deprecated things generally become *removed* in a later core GLSL version.

With all that said, I really do not know how this works fine. If you really and truly have a GL 3.1 core context, there is no command that can set the matrix associated with `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` (whether your GLSL compiler accepts it or not). `glLoadMatrix (...)`, etc. were all removed in GL 3.1.

However, I suspect you do not have what you would typically consider a *"core"* context. GL 3.1 is an ugly thing, it pre-dates the introduction of profiles to OpenGL. Although it technically *removes* almost everything that was deprecated in GL 3.0, if the extension `GL_ARB_compatibility` is present you effectively have what we now call a "compatibility profile".

Comment: Ah, GLSL compiler version makes more sense. I'm using 1.4. If I'm using compatibility context why might one computer give this message?

Comment: @JordanJHiebert: Are they different GPU vendors (e.g. NVIDIA on one and Intel or AMD on the other)? Assuming you don't have a `#version ...` directive at the top of your shader, implementations are supposed to assume the shader is written against the GLSL 1.10 specification, in which case this should only be a warning. An actual error would be something like _"shader version not supported by context"_.

Comment: @JordanJHiebert: Just read your edited question - regarding GLSL 1.40, I would point you [here](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.40.08.pdf?#page=11) under section 1.6 where it talks about deprecation's effects in a forward-compatible context.

Comment: In what situation should I get this warning? I can set the top of my shaders to "#version 150 core" and it still works with no warnings. If this was just a warning I would ignore it, but the draws are failing or being drawn without mvp.

Comment: @JordanJHiebert Can you target OpenGL 3.2 instead of 3.1? It'd make life a lot easier, really. Request a 3.2 core profile, and eliminate all of the `gl_ModelViewMatrix` stuff and go with `mat4` uniforms you setup yourself. _I have always despised OpenGL 3.1_.

Comment: I was hoping to postpone that stuff a little longer. That will take a lot of work to update. I will avoid core until I do so. I will have to find out if my friend's computer has a nvidia card. I still don't understand why one would allow deprecation while the other fails. If he doesn't have an Nvidia card this will be all the more baffling.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it appears the source of my problem was that this computer had an Nvidia graphics card. In order to get around the error (which I think should have been a simple warning) I changed my GLSL compiler version to "#version 150 compatibility" and OpenGL to 3.2

This convinced the Nvidia GLSL compiler to stop whining and do its job. I will upgrade from the ff matrix stack when I am ready.

Comment: If you do that, make sure you also request an OpenGL 3.2 compatibility profile when you create your render context. The real problem with OpenGL 3.1 is there's no way to request core vs. compatibility when you create the context, you just kind of deal with the situation yourself after the fact depending on whether you were given the `GL_ARB_compatibility` extension or not.

Comment: I did that too. Wasn't sure if that was necessary or not. Thanks for verifying.